# How to convert torchscript model to use it in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, torchscript

I got model in torchscript 'model.pt' and I want to load it in OpenCV it's possible ?
I found something in google but it didn't work ;/ Did you have something to export torscript model to opencv 'onnx'?

```
import torch

path = "model.pt"

model = torch.jit.load('model.pt')
Convert_ONNX()

def Convert_ONNX():

    # set the model to inference mode
    model.eval()

    # Let's create a dummy input tensor
    dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 32, 32, requires_grad=True)

    # Export the model
    torch.onnx.export(model,         # model being run
         dummy_input,       # model input (or a tuple for multiple inputs)
         "ImageClassifier.onnx",       # where to save the model
         export_params=True,  # store the trained parameter weights inside the model file
         opset_version=10,    # the ONNX version to export the model to
         do_constant_folding=True,  # whether to execute constant folding for optimization
         input_names = ['modelInput'],   # the model's input names
         output_names = ['modelOutput'], # the model's output names
         dynamic_axes={'modelInput' : {0 : 'batch_size'},    # variable length axes
                                'modelOutput' : {0 : 'batch_size'}})
    print(" ")
    print('Model has been converted to ONNX')
```

This code give me error:

```
RuntimeError:
Unknown builtin op: torchvision::nms.
Could not find any similar ops to torchvision::nms. This op may not exist or may not be currently supported in TorchScript.
```

Comment: try "import torchvision" before executing the function.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/dc/d70/pytorch_cls_tutorial_dnn_conversion.html may help.